# Linux - join two separate SSH connections

Tags: linux, session, authentication, ssh, ssh-keys

working on a small project and looking for some advice on how to make a portion of the project work.

Goal - join two separate ssh sessions together. I want to see if keys used to login to bastion host can be different than keys used to login to server from bastion.

Scenario - I will login to a bastion host using ssh and my keys from my machine. The bastion host will then login to the actual server on my behalf - using a different set of keys. The ssh session from my machine to the bastion host and from the bastion host to the server now needs to be connected, for me to feel as if a transparent SSH proxy is just forwarding commands.

I have read up a bit on ssh proxies but it seems like this is not implemented right off the bat (understandably). I have read - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts , I have also looked at screen sessions - but am not sure how to "merge" two ssh screen session together.

Any advice will be very helpful.

Cheers,
-J

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question fully, but here's a command that would run a command in a remote machine "hostInternal" using ssh, by first going through another remote machine "hostGateway", also using ssh:

ssh -t hostGateway ssh hostInternal "env ls"

If what you want is not just to run a command, but you want a shell in "hostInternal" that is going through "hostGateway", you can just remove the "env ls" part in the command above.

You can find a bit more explanation in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890798/why-is-the-tcgetattr-error-seen-when-ssh-is-used-for-dumping-the-backup-file-o/25676641#25676641) that explains why you want the "-t" in there sometimes.